# C Merge sort stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: recursion, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

My programme uses recursion for divide and conquer but i am getting an infinite loop due to reasons unknown. and i am still getting the unsorted array as an answer

```
/**
 * MergeSort.c
 *
 * Uses recursion for divide and conquer
 * 
 *
 * Implements merge sort for an array
 */
```

Initialize the method calls for merge and merge sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void merge(int array[6],int beg,int mid,int end);
void mergesort(int array[6],int beg,int end);
```

Initialize the display functions

```
void display(int array[6]);

int main(void)
{
     // Initializes the array
     int array[6]={3,1,2,9,5,4};
     // Initialize the beginning and the end 
     int beg=0, end=5;
     // Implement the Merge Sort 
     mergesort(array,beg,end);
     getch();
}

void mergesort(int array[6],int beg,int end) //Calls Initial merge sort
{
      int mid;
      mid=(beg+end)/2;
      while (beg<end)
      {
            mergesort(array,beg,mid);        //Left part of the array
            mergesort(array,mid+1,end);      //Right part of the array
            merge(array,beg,mid,end);        //merge two sorted arrays
      }
 }

 //merges two subarrays
void merge(int array[6],int beg,int mid,int end)
{
     int temp[6]; //Declare a temp array for storing the sorted elements
     int k=beg;     
     int i=beg;   //initialize the pointers for two sub arrays
     int j=mid;

     while (i<mid && j<end)
       {
            if(array[i]<array[j])
              {
                 temp[k]=array[i];
                 i++;
                 k++;
              }
            else
              {
                 temp[k]=array[j];
                 j++;
                 k++;
              }              
        }

    //Clearing any remaining elements in the sub array
     while (i<mid) 
      {
           temp[k]=array[i];
           i++;
           k++; 
      }

    //Clearing any remaining elements in the sub array
    while (j<end) 
      {
          temp[k]=array[j];
          j++;
          k++; 
      }

    //Reassign the sorted elements to the original array
    for(i=0,k=0;i<end,k<end;i++,k++)     
      {
          array[i]=temp[k];                                      
      }
    //prints the individual array elements  
    display(array);           //display array
}

//Displays the entire array

void display(int array[6])
{
     //prints the individual array elements
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
      {
             printf("%d ",array[i]); //prints the individual array elements
      }
     printf("\n"); //Enter a new line after every iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from mergesort function,

```
while (beg<end)
  {
        mergesort(array,beg,mid);        //Left part of the array
        mergesort(array,mid+1,end);      //Right part of the array
        merge(array,beg,mid,end);        //merge two sorted arrays
  }
```

beg and end won't be editted. So it will do somethingin this loop forever.
I think you should change from **while** into **if**.

And moreover, if your end is 5 (last index in that array/segment) the last element in the segment won't be sorted. That's mean this array won't be sorted. You have to change to...

```
 while (i<mid && j<=end) //from j<end to j<=end and for another loop
   {
        if(array[i]<array[j])
          {
             temp[k]=array[i];
             i++;
             k++;
          }
        else
          {
             temp[k]=array[j];
             j++;
             k++;
          }              
    }
```

Good luck on DQ<3